# R Month by Month Percent Growth on an XTS objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts

How might I plot month to month growth for the following data:

```
             A
2008-07-01   0
2008-08-01  87
2008-09-01 257
2008-10-01 294
2008-11-01 325
2008-12-01 299
```

(In dput format, before Joshua hunts me down and murders me in my sleep):

```
structure(c(0L, 87L, 257L, 294L, 325L, 299L), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXt", 
"POSIXct"), .indexTZ = "", index = structure(c(1214884800, 1217563200, 
1220241600, 1222833600, 1225512000, 1228107600), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXt", 
"POSIXct")), .Dim = c(6L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "A"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Comment: Pssh, I wouldn't do anything that harsh... I may douse you with a bucket of ice water though. ;-)

Comment: Looks like `Delt` from quantmod might be what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define growth: first difference? Percentages?   In either case just compute and then plot:

```
R> index(KB) <- as.Date(index(KB))    ## what you have are dates, not datetimes
R> barplot(diff(KB), ylab="Change in value", main="Growth")
```

[image]

You can also use a standard line plot:

```
R> plot(diff(KB), type='b', ylab="Change in value", main="Growth")
```

[image]

and change the `type=` argument of this plot to show bars etc pp.  *Normally* would plot percentage changes but given your first datapoint this is inadmissible here (as noted by Gavin) so diffs it is for this illustration.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `dput()` data in object `dat`, and assuming you mean the month percentage change over previous month, then:

```
R> (diff(dat) / lag(dat)) * 100
                            A
2008-07-01 05:00:00        NA
2008-08-01 05:00:00       Inf
2008-09-01 05:00:00 195.40230
2008-10-01 05:00:00  14.39689
2008-11-01 04:00:00  10.54422
2008-12-01 05:00:00  -8.00000
```

(Forgot the plot)

```
plot((diff(dat) / lag(dat)) * 100, main = "",
     ylab = "% growth (for some definition of % growth)")
```

[image]

Not sure how best to handle the second month - % growth was infinite...

Comment: Ah okay, so `Delt` does the same thing with its default as `Diff / Lag`