# R Add previous month value as a column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with date and price by month:

```
set.seed(128)
dat <- data.table(DATE=c("2014-01-01","2014-02-01","2014-03-01","2014-04-01",
                "2014-05-01","2014-06-01","2014-07-01","2014-08-01",
                "2014-09-01","2014-10-01","2014-11-01","2014-12-01"),
              PRICE=rnorm(n = 12, mean=100, sd=15))
dat

      DATE     PRICE
1: 2014-01-01 108.83590
2: 2014-02-01  67.69042
3: 2014-03-01 122.28905
4: 2014-04-01  93.50617
5: 2014-05-01 109.57878
6: 2014-06-01 128.81537
7: 2014-07-01  82.67295
8: 2014-08-01  68.25281
9: 2014-09-01  82.98265
10: 2014-10-01 124.28960
11: 2014-11-01  84.61275
12: 2014-12-01  93.14938
```

I would like to add the previous months price as a column in the data table, so the table would look like this:

```
      DATE     PRICE    PRICE_PREV
1: 2014-01-01 108.83590
2: 2014-02-01  67.69042 108.83590
3: 2014-03-01 122.28905 67.69042
...
10: 2014-10-01 124.28960 82.98265
11: 2014-11-01  84.61275 124.28960
12: 2014-12-01  93.14938  84.61275
```

How would I accomplish this in R?

Comment: I don't see the point . . your data looks wrong now in your expected output format . . you have 108.83 against Feb instead of Jan . .

Comment: The new column would allow me to make calculations of month over month data such as price difference (e.g. dat$PRICE_DIFF <- dat$PRICE - dat$PRICE_PREV)

Comment: why don't you convert date to as.date and plot month over month change using `diff` function ?  refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876928/r-month-by-month-percent-growth-on-an-xts-objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `shift` from `data.table` [v >= 1.9.5 (on GitHub)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
dat[, PRICE_PREV := shift(PRICE)]
dat
#           DATE     PRICE PRICE_PREV
#  1: 2014-01-01 108.95158         NA
#  2: 2014-02-01 107.23918  108.95158
#  3: 2014-03-01 124.96608  107.23918
#  4: 2014-04-01  99.61007  124.96608
#  5: 2014-05-01 118.13540   99.61007
#  6: 2014-06-01 108.70528  118.13540
#  7: 2014-07-01  93.12482  108.70528
#  8: 2014-08-01 100.06829   93.12482
#  9: 2014-09-01 103.14932  100.06829
# 10: 2014-10-01 122.66710  103.14932
# 11: 2014-11-01 104.84064  122.66710
# 12: 2014-12-01 113.37610  104.84064
```

If you have an older version (v < 1.9.5) you could also do

```
dat[, PRICE_PREV := c(NA, PRICE[-.N])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first term has no known price for previous month (I'm assuming - if it does, you can replace the NA with it).

The following code should work fine. The first line creates a new vector, the second adds it as a column to dat and the third removes the vector (as it's now in dat and we don't need it separately).

```
PRICE_PREV <- c(NA, dat$PRICE[1:length(dat$PRICE)-1])
dat <- cbind(dat, PRICE_PREV)
rm(PRICE_PREV)
```